# ngx-translate object interpolation

Tags: angular, internationalization, ngx-translate

I have a structured translation file as follows:

```
 "myApp":{
  "errorMessages": {
    "unauthorized": "This {{serviceName}} account is not valid for the {{appName}} app.",
    "missing_role": "You can not use this account to access {{appName}} application"
  }
}
```

If I access single translation directly, I can easily use interpolation:

```
const appNameObject = { appName: 'My app', serviceName: 'My Service' };
const unauthorizedErrorMessage = translateService.instant('myApp.errorMessages.unauthorized', appNameObject);
```

But sometimes I would like to get all keys in a structured object at once - and interpolation seems not to work in this case

```
 const errorMessages = translateService.instant('myApp.errorMessages', appNameObject);
```

Can I get this working?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The ngx-translate doesn't support this.

If you want/expect to get an object that looks like this

```
{
  "unauthorized": "This My Service account is not valid for the My app app.",
  "missing_role": "You can not use this account to access My app application"
}
```

You have to actually create it yourself the way you use interpolation in the example that works

Answer (score 1):

You can interpolate your parameters using a regex. In the `.replace()` function, call them with an object or a table using the match string.

Use the regex `/{{(\w+)}}/gm` to match the string to replace

```js
const appNameObject: any = {
  serviceName: 'potatoe'
  appName: 'jam'
}

const message: string = (
  await this.translateService
  .get('myApp.errorMessages.unauthorized')
  .toPromise()
)
.replace(
  /{{(\w+)}}/gm,
  (fullMatch, match) => appNameObject[match]
);
```

### Edit

Please, refer to [Atscub answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68566386/9197553) which apply a regex on every elements of the translation object (even nested ones) using `JSON.stringify`.

My implementation of a NgxInterpolation method without JSON import (es2019+):

```js
const NgxInterpolation: any = (translationObject: any, interpolationObject: {[k: string]: any}) => {
    switch(typeof translationObject){
        case "object":
            return Object.fromEntries(
                Object.entries(translationObject).map(
                ([k, v], i) => [k, NgxInterpolation(v, interpolationObject)]
                )
            );
        case "string":
            return translationObject.replace(
                /{{(\w+)}}/gm,
                (fullMatch, match) => interpolationObject[match]
            );
        default:
            return translationObject;
    }
}
```

Use it as follow:

```js
const errorMessages: any = NgxInterpolation(
  this.translateService.instant('myApp.errorMessages'),
  appNameObject
)
```

### Ngx-Translate Parser

ngx-translate has a [parser](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#parser) and the `get` function from the translation service accept an [interpolation object](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#methods).

for the json file `en.json`:

```json
{
    "HOME": {
        "HELLO": "hello {{value}}"
    }
}
```

you can interpolate the key `value` set to `world` for the translation string `HELLO` as follow:

```js
// With the interpolationObject parameter from the get (or instant) method
this.translateService.get('HELLO', { value: 'world' })

// With the interpolation method from the ngx-translate parser
this.translateService.parser.interpolate(
  this.translateService.instant("HELLO"),
  { value: 'world' }
)
```

The translation only works for translation string. If you want to apply interpolation on every translation string by using ngx-translate methods, you need to define a method as follow (es2019+):

```js
NgxObjectInterpolation(
  translationObject: any,
  interpolationObject: { [k: string]: any }
) {
  switch (typeof translationObject) {
    case "object":
      return Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(translationObject).map(([k, v], i) => [
          k,
          this.NgxObjectInterpolation(v, interpolationObject),
        ])
      );
    case "string":
      return this.translateService.parser.interpolate(
        translationObject,
        interpolationObject
      );
    default:
      return translationObject;
  }
}
```

Use it like this:

```js
this.NgxObjectInterpolation(
  this.translateService.instant("HELLO"),
  { value: "world" }
);
```

Comment: This solution works well for strings. The OP asked for object interpolation. You would have to iterate (recursively) over the object to replace in nested properties.

Comment: Hello Atscub, you're right and your answer is the go-to... or is it ? Newer versions of ngx-translate support interpolation (hallelujah). Need to test if it work on every translations when retrieving a parent node.

Answer (score 1):

Although it can't be done out of the box, you can easily accomplish what you need using
[JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) /
[JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and interpolate by yourself using regular expressions.

1. Define a function in your `utils` service or any other place like this:

   ```js
   const objectInterpolate = (obj: any, params: {[k: string]: any}) => {
     return JSON.parse(
       JSON.stringify(obj)
         .replace(/{{\s*([^}\s]+)\s*}}/gm, (_, group) => params[group] ?? "")
     );
   }
   ```
2. Then use it in your anywhere:

   ```js
    this.translate.get("myApp.errorMessages")
      .subscribe(value => {
        this.errorMessages = this.utils.objectInterpolate(
          value, 
          {
            paramName: paramValue,
            paramName2: paramValue2,
            ...
          }
        );
      );
   ```